# AWS DMS replication using CDC is failing with distribution not installed error

Tags: sql-server, aws-dms

I'm trying to perform replication from one SQL Server to another SQL server (both are unmanaged databases on EC2 and not RDS). I have created the DMS replication instances, endpoints and task. My task for full migration is working fine however when I create another task with migration type as 'replicate data changes only' then I get below error:

> Last Error Fatal error has occurred Task error notification received from subtask 0, thread 0 [reptask/replicationtask.c:2883] [1022505] Failed (retcode -1) to execute statement; RetCode: SQL_ERROR SqlState: 42000 NativeError: 20028 Message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The Distributor has not been installed correctly. Could not enable database for publishing. Line: 1 Column: -1; Failed while preparing stream component 'st_0_WPIBNBAM25DCP2I77RFCFNVP3H6AYOCBOU4W5QY'.; Cannot initialize subtask; Stream component 'st_0_WPIBNBAM25DCP2I77RFCFNVP3H6AYOCBOU4W5QY' terminated [reptask/replicationtask.c:2891] [1022505] Stop Reason FATAL_ERROR Error Level FATAL

It says the distributor has not been installed. I'm using Mac with Dbeaver as an SQL client to connect to databases. How to fix this issue by installing the distributor?